# ClickConfirm Directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working with AngularJs in managing of books, I defined a directive clickConfirmDirective to use it when I want to delete a book
When I first access to the list of books and I select an item to delete it, the dialog of confirmation appears and delete works proporly
But when I add or modify a book, then go back to the list to delete a book, the clickConfirm dialog appears but delete() doesn't work. 
When I replace these code:

```
<a click-confirm="delete(id)" confirm-message"Do you want to delete it?" confirm-btn-text ="supprimer"> Supprimer </a>
```

with this :

```
<a ng-click="delete(id)" > supprimer </>
```

and it works perfectly, who have any idea why the clickConfirmDirective doesn't work after an add or modify operation?

Comment: You need to $compile the elements you dynamically add.

Comment: Perhaps you should share your code for the `clickConfirm` directive.

Comment: @Shomz thank you! I read about $compile and I guess this is the answer of what I need, do you have any example of $compile please?